# How can I change xcode project's firebase database?

Tags: xcode, firebase

I have a project with connected firebase database. I need to change that database to another database for production. How can I change firebase database of this project? Is change `GoogleService-Info.plist` change enough for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you initialize Firebase in your project, but by default it will indeed [reads the configuration from the `GoogleService-info.plist` file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#add-config-file). Replacing this file with the one from your new project, will make your app read the configuration data for that new project.